# How do I stop the Disqus comment count from loading on Blogger post timestamps?

Tags: blogger, disqus

Disqus seems to automatically add a comment count link next to timestamps on Blogger posts.

[image: comment count]

I don't want the count to show.  It's at the bottom of my posts right next to the disqus iframe which already shows the count.

[image: double comment count]

I know how to **hide** the item by adding css.

```
.disqus-blogger-comment-link {
  display: none;
}
```

**What I'm looking for is a way to stop the javascript from loading at all to save on page load speed.**

Either via disqus (somehow) or blogger (via the theme editor html) would work, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Disqus code, There are three script tags, Remove the last one

Remove this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
var bloggerjs = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
bloggerjs.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
bloggerjs.async = true;
bloggerjs.src = &#39;//&#39; + disqus_shortname + &#39;.disqus.com/blogger_index.js&#39;;
(document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0] || document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;body&#39;)[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
})();
</script>
```